# Swift delegate and protocol not working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I need the steppers in my ViewController to update manually from my other class. The variables are updated in my second class, but the steppers don't reset like they are suppose to.  I think i am calling my delegate incorrectly.

**ViewController:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CircleViewDelegate {

    var colors = CircleView()
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView1: CircleView! 
    @IBOutlet weak var redStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var redValue: UILabel!
    @IBAction func stepperChange(sender: UIStepper) {
        circleView1.redd1 = Int(redStepper.value);
        redValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
    }
    func updateRedStepperValue(value: Double) {

        redStepper.value = value
        redValue.text = Int(colors.redd1.value).description;
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
        if let viewControllers = app.window?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers {
            viewControllers.forEach { vc in
                if let cont = vc as? CircleView {
                    cont.delegate = self
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Class:**

```
protocol CircleViewDelegate {
    func updateRedStepperValue(value: Double)
    func updateGreenStepperValue(value: Double)
    func updateBlueStepperValue(value: Double)
}

class CircleView: UIView {
    var delegate: CircleViewDelegate?
    var redd1 = 0

    func updateValues() {
        if(redd1 == Int(red1)) {
            redd1 = 0;
            delegate?.updateRedStepperValue(0.0)//
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your delegate being set?  Your technique is unorthodox. Normally you would set the delegate in prepareForSegue

Comment: But what if it is a custom class or a `UIView`, then what is customary? is putting that into `viewDidLoad()` bad practice here?

Comment: You seem to be confusing ViewControllers and Views. You have `if let cont = vc as? CircleView`, but CircleView is a UIView, not a UIViewController. Therefore it will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your `CircleView`'s added to the view of your view controllers:

```
viewControllers.forEach { $0.view.subviews.forEach { ($0 as? CircleView)?.delegate = self } }
```

For fun. I'm not sure what you're exactly doing but you seem to want to set the delegate of all existing `CircleView`'s. There are numerous **better** ways than iterating through all the view controller's views.

**Wrong:**

```
viewControllers.forEach { vc in
    if let cont = vc as? CircleView {
        cont.delegate = self
    }
}
```

As pointed out by Michael in the comments, `vc` is a view controller and `CircleView` is an `UIView` resulting in your delegate never be set.

---

**Note:** this answer **only** shows what he's doing wrong and is by no means suggesting how to do things.